# why am i getting the error ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'publications' in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have a many to many relationship between a model called topic and publication , when i'm trying yo serializing data related to the publication model i get the error below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIvOH.png)
here is my model :

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images/')
class Topic(models.Model) : 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(
        Publication,
        related_name='topic'
    )
    def __str__(self) : 
        return self.name
```

here are my serializers :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username' , 'profile_pic']
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender =UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta : 
        model = Comment
        fields = ['sender']
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta : 
        model = Topic
        fields = '__all__'
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic = TopicSerializer(many=False)
    publication_comments = CommentSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta : 
        model = Publication
        fields = '__all__'
```

and here are my views :

```
@decorators.api_view(['GET'])
def get_publications(request,pk=None):
    if pk : 
        instance = Publication.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return response.Response(
            PublicationSerializer(instance , many=None).data)
    topic = request.query_params.get('topic') if request.query_params.get('topic') else ''
    title = request.query_params.get('title') if request.query_params.get('title') else ''
    qs = Publication.objects.all()
    data = PublicationSerializer(qs, many =True).data
    return response.Response(data , status=200)
```

i tried to return a filtered queryset

Answer (score 0):

set many=True:

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic = TopicSerializer(many=True)
    publication_comments = CommentSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta : 
        model = Publication
        fields = '__all__'
```